# Use Options When Installing Through yum

Tags: redhat, yum

I'm having an error. And the solution seems to be to install ImageMagick with the following configuration options:

```
./configure -–disable-openmp -–enable-shared
```

but I'm using yum to install things (On Red Hat), so I don't know how to do these command line configure options.

Does anyone know how to get yum to install and configure with command line arguments like these?

Thanks in advance,
--d

Comment: Doubtful that's the problem.  Please post the actual error that you are getting.

Comment: It was. Though posting the error would have been a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configure is run at the command line when you are building from source.  If the binary rpm is not built the way that you need, then you have to download the source tarball and rebuild it.  Instructions for doing this will be in a file called INSTALL when you unpack the tarball.  This also means you need the compiler and other development tools.